# Is it possible to check if a file on HDFS is a SequenceFile without (mis)using exceptions?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sequencefile

I want to read a specific `SequenceFile` from HDFS from a client application. I can do this by using the `SequenceFile.Reader` and it works fine. But is it also possible to check *whether* a file *is* a `SequenceFile` other from analyzing the thrown `IOException`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug around the Hadoop documentation, source code and web and found a solution: `SequenceFile`s start with a four byte header reading `SEQn` where `n` is the version of the file (a positive, one-byte number, but never greater than 6). So for the check, one can do the following:

1. Open the file as a normal `FSDataInputStream` with `FileSystem.open`
2. Read the first three bytes as an ASCII string
3. Check if they say `SEQ` - if not, no `SequenceFile`
4. Check if the next byte is less than or equal to 6, and greater than 0, if yes -> `SequenceFile`

This should be a utility method in SequenceFile, e.g. `SequenceFile.isSequenceFile`

EDIT: I posted a JIRA about this: [HDFS-7378](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-7378)

Comment: It would be great if you could also post the link to the document where you found it.

Comment: I found this out by single-stepping the opening of a `SequenceFile` in the debugger.